# Vue + webpack, convert font files to base64

Tags: vue.js, webpack, base64, urlloader

I'm writing a library to import into other projects, to share custom components and styles.
Problem is with font files, .woff/.ttf/etc.

```
//_fonts.scss
$woff_path: '~/woff';
$ttf_path: '~/ttf';

@font-face {
    font-family: "MyOpensans";
    src: url($woff_path + "opensans-regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2");
    src: url($woff_path + "opensans-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
    src: url($woff_path + "OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("font-type");
    font-style: normal;
...
}

$testfont: "MyOpensans", wingdings;
```

When I use $testfont in my scss, the url uses relative path, which of course doesn't work when imported into other projects.  So, my thought was just use base64:

```
src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64;XXXX);
```

Works fine if I run the .woff files through a base64 convertor, and paste into _fonts.scss.  But, I'd like webpack to do it for me.  I've tried both base64-inline-loader and url-loader.  Neither have worked.
A bit more digging with url-loader.  if I `import "@/assets/woff/opensans-regular.webfont.woff2";` in my main.ts, I can see it does base64 it into a variable in the main source, but my _fonts.scss of course has no idea of this, and my _fonts.scss still has src as the relative path.  It seems as though url-loader does nothing with url() inside scss.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way I can get webpack to turn my url(*file path*) into url(*data:xxx*) for me?  Or some other way to get custom fonts to work when compiled to a library?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using something like [base64-inline-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-inline-loader)

As per the example on that page:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        use: ['base64-inline-loader']
    }
]
```